# MongoDB Cluster upgrade to use SSL/TLS failed

Tags: mongodb, ssl, tls1.2, x509certificate, mongodb-cluster

I reproduce MongoDB Cluster replica-set and added user like admin with Non-SSL following below link.

- **Link :** https://github.com/arun2pratap/mongodbClusterForWindowsOneClick
- **Environment :**

  - OS : Windows 2019 server ( set all instance in one windows server)
  - 1 mongos ( **port** : 26000 )
  - 2 shards ( **port** : sh01 : 27011 ~ 27013 / sh02 : 27021 ~ 27023 )
  - 1 conf servers ( **port** : csrs : 26001 ~ 26003 )

After reproduce Cluster with Non-SSL, I tried to upgrade Cluster to use SSL following MongoDB Manual for 4.5 and other links but I couldn't found clear answer or guide.
Below are my refer links.

- https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/upgrade-cluster-to-ssl/
- https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-keyfile-access-control/
- https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/cannot-start-mongodb-service-after-configuring-tls/2802
- [MongoDB Shell connection errors using test self signed certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61277115/mongodb-shell-connection-errors-using-test-self-signed-certificates)
- https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/creating-openssl-server-certificates-for-testing-failed/109058

I just configured conf files like sh011.conf following manuals, guides and started. but server seems only started csrs instances. because, I couldn't found other instance's port numbers.

**1. sh011.conf**

```
sharding:
  clusterRole: shardsvr
replication:
  replSetName: sh01
net:
  bindIpAll: true
  port: 27011
  tls:
    mode: requireTLS
    certificateKeyFile: C:\database\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\certifications\test-server1.pem
    CAFile: C:\database\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\certifications\test-ca.pem
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: sh01/sh011/log/sh011.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: sh01/sh011/db/
```

**2. mongos.conf**

```
sharding:
  configDB: csrs/WIN-BKEV4AO0KED:26001,WIN-BKEV4AO0KED:26002,WIN-BKEV4AO0KED:26003
net:
  bindIpAll: true
  port: 26000
  tls:
    mode: requireTLS
    certificateKeyFile: C:\database\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\certifications\test-server1.pem
    CAFile: C:\database\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\certifications\test-ca.pem
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: router/log/mongos.log
  logAppend: true
security:
  authorization: enabled
  clusterAuthMode: x509
```

**3. "netstat -an" output**

```
C:\database\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin>netstat -an

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:22             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5432           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5985           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:26001          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:26002          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:26003          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:47001          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

When I checked log files, each shard nodes occurred SSL error like below

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-09T14:34:54.933+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4712102, "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"Host failed in replica set","attr":{"replicaSet":"csrs","host":"WIN-BKEV4AO0KED:26001","error":{"code":6,"codeName":"HostUnreachable","errmsg":"Error connecting to WIN-BKEV4AO0KED:26001 (192.168.100.202:26001) :: caused by :: SSL peer certificate validation failed: (80096004)The signature of the certificate cannot be verified."},"action":{"dropConnections":true,"requestImmediateCheck":false,"outcome":{"host":":26001","success":false}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-05-09T14:34:55.164+09:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4333222, "ctx":"ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor","msg":"RSM received failed isMaster","attr":{"host":"WIN-BKEV4AO0KED:26003","error":"HostUnreachable: Error connecting to WIN-BKEV4AO0KED:26003 (192.168.100.202:26003) :: caused by :: SSL peer certificate validation failed: (80096004)The signature of the certificate cannot be verified.","replicaSet":"csrs","isMasterReply":"{}"}}
```

I thought, that issues cause is relate host names so, I configured hosts file.
Then, re-created certification files for CA, Server, Client following manual.

**1. openssl-test-server.conf**

```
[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = WIN-BKEV4AO0KED
IP.1 = 192.168.100.202

[ req_dn ]
countryName = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default = AA
countryName_min = 2
countryName_max = 2

stateOrProvinceName = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = City
stateOrProvinceName_max = 64

localityName = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default = City
localityName_max = 64

organizationName = Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default = DevCompany
organizationName_max = 64

organizationalUnitName = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
organizationalUnitName_default = Dev
organizationalUnitName_max = 64

commonName = Common Name (eg, YOUR name)
commonName_default = WIN-BKEV4AO0KED
commonName_max = 64
```

But, still mongos and other instances are not started.
Finally, I think some configuration is wrong. I want know what I missed or wrong for SSL.

Comment: Are you sure, the mongod/mongos do not even start?

Comment: Hi, Wernfried.  
Thank you for the reply.  

Yes, as I mentioned 26000 that mongos instance port seems not opened.
And I couldn't found process in "windows taskbar" and "task manager". 
So, I convinced mongos was not started.
And all instances occurred SSL peer error on log files.

Is there any other way to check that mongos and shards are started?
And what I missed or wrong point for SSL?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found what is cause of issue and How to start MongoDB Cluster with SSL Myself.

1st, Root cause is that I couldn't start MongoDB instances like mongos, mongod with SSL enable and missed some parameters while starting like below :

1. before start command

   > $ mongod -f csrs1.conf
2. modified start command

   > $ mongod -f csrs1.conf --tlsMode requireTLS --tlsCertificateKeyFile test-server1.pem --tlsCAFile test-ca.pem

**Note** : I was not set MongoDB as service and just control through prompt

When I generated certification base on default setting and start each MongoDB with new command, that was working fine.

And I tried modify START.bat file for convenience like above new command.
But, that was not working. So, I opened prompt for each nodes and executed start command manually.

I hope this information will help.